# In Gmail, how to a delete an email and view the next email?

Tags: gmail

Often when I am reading a set of emails, I wish to delete (or archive) the email I am reading **and** move to the next email in the list (inbox or search result).  However, when I press “archive”, etc., it does the action and moves back to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First turn on [keyboard shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594) in settings.

Now you can use <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to archive and move to the previous/next conversation.

Comment: Ok... I'll just delete my answer!! How did I miss these shortcuts..! +2 if I could :D

Comment: thanks, do you know how to **Delete** and move to the previous/next conversation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new 'labs' feature called 'Auto-advance' that looks like it will do what you want.

You can access the labs settings by clicking on the small green icon next to your email address on the top-right of the page.

Hope this helps.